# Open source alternative to Google Earth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openstreetmap

I need to build a website which needs to perform the following tasks:

1. Display a web map with topographical details
2. On the map show a set of selected streets
3. When a street is selected show a set of points of interest on that street

The constraints are:

1. Ruby on Rails
2. Everything in the stack must be open source

I've given an interested look at [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/The_Rails_Port) will it work for the needed tasks?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the Google Maps API? Just because it isn't open source doesn't mean you can't use it.

Comment: @warrior Google Maps is not free for commercial apps, one could even say it's rather pricey.

Comment: You might want to try this question over at http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [Mapfish](http://mapfish.org/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/). OpenstreetMap will only allow you to load maps in a visualizer (think of it more like a collaborative geodatabank), and Openlayers is more or less Openstreetmap's little brother / visualizer / tool for edition. I heard Mapfish has a plugin for rails integration, but i don't know what it's worth. Good luck learning the API of your choice !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Nasa World Wind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/).  It's a java app, but I've seen evidence that you can work with it from jruby without too much trouble.

Comment: Anything about OpenStreetMap?